# Salvar foto de perfil do usuario ao relogar no sistema de um chat usando socket

Tags: java, socket, chat

Desenvolvi um chat em Java utilizando *sockets* no qual tem que escolher uma foto de perfil após o login ser feito.

Minha dúvida é: Como que eu faria para salvar essa foto escolhida pelo usuário e reutilizá-la num login futuro? Da mesma forma que é o Facebook quando você coloca uma foto, ela aparece lá novamente no perfil.

O código que coloquei abaixo é para pegar a foto, ele pega a imagem e joga em uma JLabel:

```
foto.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            foto.setToolTipText("Altere sua foto.");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            e.getComponent().setCursor(
                    Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "png", "jpg", "gif");

            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                BufferedImage image = null;
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(file);
                    foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(130,
                            130, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Poderia explicar exatamente onde está tendo um problema? Além do mais, como seu código se relaciona com a sua dúvida?

Comment: Desculpe pela minha falta te atenção editei a pergunta, e agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Oi, jonathan, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. O site funciona diferente de fórums e redes sociais, o **[Tour]** é rápido e explica bem. Dei uma simplificada no seu texto para ir direto ao assunto.

Comment: Esta pergunta não tem como ser respondida, pois o código fornecido tem pouca relação com o problema dado. O código apenas carrega uma imagem no disco e mostra na tela, e isto pouco tem a ver com sockets. Além disso, esta pergunta está abandonada, já foi fechada e reaberta e eu já ia votar para fechar de novo.

Answer (score 0):

Persista essa informação no servidor do seu chat. De uma maneira bem simplista, você pode criar um diretório na máquina onde está seu server de chat (usando o id do usuario como nome da foto, por exemplo). Aí quando o usuário se reconectar no server, você devolve o byte array da foto no socket e monta no cliente.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo?